# Creating Scratch Org results in error

Tags: vs-code, scratch-org, vscode-dx

- Created a scratch org in VSCode.
- Trying to push source to default scratch org results in the following errors:

1. The global picklist cannot be resolved
2. Global value set cannot be resolved
3. In field: columns - no CustomField named "xyz" found
4. Field does not exist - check spelling

There are few more errors, but I am not listing them all here.

What is the cause of these errors and what can be done to resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing metadata, specifically a [GlobalValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm). The other related errors are cascading errors from the fact you're missing one or more files. Make sure you retrieve the GVS, then try deploying again.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m GlobalValueSet:ValueSetName -u sourceOrg
sfdx force:source:push
```

Comment: thank you for response. There are a lot of these that are missing. Is it possible to include all global value sets? And is there a way to include it in the config file so that we don't have to type it every time?

Comment: @Imtiyaz (a) `-m GlobalValueSet` will get all the files, and (b) once you commit those files to your repo, you shouldn't need to do it again unless you change those values and forget to pull.

Comment: thank you. that resolved most the errors. I am still getting errors I will list below. Is there any documentation for missing metadata (I tried googling for it, but I may not be searching for the right terms). Here are some of the remaining errors:

In field: group - no group named "xxx" found
In field: queue - no queue named "xxx" found
Field does not exist - check spelling
Invalid field

Comment: @Imtiyaz That ends up being the same type of issue. You'd have to retrieve Queue and Role, possibly more. You might need to clean up your metadata to avoid these dependencies. It's really hard to get right the first time; you have to get a feel for things, unfortunately.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help.